# How to encrypt the password in the login form using php

Tags: php, sql-server, hash

I created a form to insert data(username & password) in sql server. the password there is already encrypted. my problem now is am I going to insert the $encrypt_pass in my parametrized query.

```
<?php 
$pass= $_POST['pass'];
$encrypt_pass=md5($pass);
$params = array($_POST['user'], $encrypt_pass);
$server = "MELODY-PC\SQLEXPRESS"; 
$options = array("Database"=>"customerdb", "UID"=>"dbadmin", "PWD"=>"melodyjerah"); 
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounting_login WHERE username = ? and password = ?"; 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params); 
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) 
{ 
    header("Location: page_accounting.php");    
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "Invalid USERNAME or PASSWORD!"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: md5() is not sufficient for encryption. password_hash()  or equivalent is the way to go.

Comment: Is it working? What is the error if any?

Comment: Also what is the concern regarding the parameterized query?

Comment: investigate the use of SHA256 encryption and create a randomly created salt as well to store in the db so you can compare the salted and hashed password against the stored versions

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question. Try rephrasing your post so we know what you need.   If it's encrypted in the database you should be able to `SELECT` it by encrypting the user input and then comparing it to whats in your database.

Comment: @Lim the error in login is: Undefined index: d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4 in C:\xampp\htdocs\rgpi\connectdb.php on line 4

Comment: @Rasclatt I used parameterized query so that it will be protected from sql injection.

Comment: @lame I asked "how to encrypt the password in the login form"

Comment: I know what parameterizing does, but what is the concern regarding parameterizing and password encryption/hashing? You parameterize it normally, as a string.

Comment: See the answer below, that is how to hash your password and store it. Your example throws and error because you are creating an index in the post that doesn't exist. To fix yours (I don't recommend you use the method you have created), you do `$params = array($_POST['user'], $encrypt_pass); `

Comment: @Rasclatt thank you. that was my mistake. it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have php 5.5, use this

```
$password = password_hash($password_from_input, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); //store this in db
```

In login_form.php

```
$true = password_verify($password_from_input, $password_in_db); // returns TRUE or FALSE
```

You do not need salt, just a password column will do